# Limiting CPU usage for a Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, cpu-usage, runtime.exec

Is it possible limiting CPU usage for a `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`?

Following the question in the title I am wondering if exists any library or so to limit the 
CPU usage when a process is run by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`. Out of Java I can use shell commands like `cpulimit` etc, but I am curious about a Java alternative.

Comment: There is no native Java, platform-independent way to do this.

Comment: we can only set the memory (heap) size, there is none for CPU usage,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Out of Java I can use shell commands like 'cpulimit' etc, but I am curious about a Java alternative.

You would do it the same way; e.g. by wrapping the command to be "limited" in a shell script / batch file that sets the limits using the relevant commands.

(Java doesn't provide direct support for this kind of thing, so you have no choice but to resort to platform specific "hacks" like this.)